# Java passing large objects best practices

Tags: java

I have been working with Java for about a year now on a legacy application.  As I understand the language and application better, I am starting to have some questions about best practices.  Here is one example:

The application is somewhat of a of case manager, where the case is a large object with many nested objects and fields.  Most actions in the application revolve around the state of this case to determine the behavior.

We have lots of massive methods that basically fetch -> update state -> make auxiliary calls to other methods, or web service calls to notify other applications -> persist state change to DB.

As I try to split up these large methods, I find myself constantly needing to pass the large case object by reference to use its data and nested objects, as opposed to passing its ID and pulling it from the database through many joins.

However, these methods might also be more reusable if I only pass the ID and let them look-up the case information from the database.

For example:

```
methodA:
 - fetch case from DB
 -> notificationManager.sendCaseStatusChange(case, status)
    - send update with data from case
```

In this scenario sendCaseStatusChange may be called from different areas, where case may not always be loaded into memory

```
methodA:
 - fetch case from DB
 -> notificationManager.sendCaseStatusChange(caseID, status)
    - fetch case from DB
    - send update with data from case
```

Here sendCaseStatusChange is more independent, as it can pull the information needed on it's own.  However, it would incur another database hit since we already have the case in methodA.

Any suggestions of how to best handle this case, or experiences with similar trade-offs would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: "Might be more reusable" doesn't really warrant modifying working code, especially when it involves an additional database hit. With JPA you *might* leverage the 1st level cache when using `em.find()`, but I wouldn't go there based on just hopes and assumptions.

Comment: There's also the question of testability: if your methods all start with fetching things from database, you're going to struggle to unit test them. But at the same time if they depend on a massive object being constructed first, that's not ideal either.

Comment: Fair enough :)  Maybe "best practices" isn't the best term for what I'm asking.  I'm looking more along the lines of what have others done in this scenario and what they would recommend based on their experiences.  I'm sure I'm not the first to come across this trade off.  I might add that the notificationManager.sendCaseStatusChange is new code that I'm trying to make a design decision on.

Comment: If you want a method that takes the id only, you don't need to replace the old one. Create an additional method that loads the object, then delegates to the one taking the object as parameter.

Comment: @Kayaman That's (in a nutshell) what I just considered to write as an answer, but I think that the question is a bit too vague to really give a "good" answer anyhow...

Answer (score 0):

Overload the method sendCaseStatusChange, so you can expose two methods that can be called from different clients. Internally you will have something like this

```
public void sendCaseStatusChange(Case case, Status status) {
...
...
}

public void sendCaseStatusChange(Long caseId, Status status) 
    Case case = findCase(caseId);
    sendCaseStatusChange(case,status);
}
```

So if a client have already loaded Case can use the version that doesn't hit the database